# How to get the hours component of NSDate according to local time zone?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to determine whether a time stamp belongs to a set of time ranges I've established. I'm using the following code:

```
- (BOOL) timeStampInTimeRange: (NSDate *)timestamp {

    NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitHour fromDate:timestamp];
    NSInteger hour = [components hour];

    for(int i = 0; i < [timesOfDay count]; i++){
        NSArray *range = timesOfDay[i];
        if( (hour >= [range[0] intValue]) && (hour < [range[1] intValue]) ){
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

However this is actually checking the hour of the GMT time zone and not my local time zone. I see how to adjust an entire date to print it out according to a local time zone, but how can  grab just the hour according to local time zone?

Comment: `NSCalendar` uses the local time zone unless you tell it otherwise. One of: your date, your device's settings, or the values in `timesOfDay` are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is doing exactly what you describe: It takes an NSDate as it's timestamp parameter, then calculates the hour number for that date in the current timezone. You should log that value to confirm that you are getting what you expect.

You then compare your hour value against values stored into an array timesOfDay. My guess is that your hour ranges are wrong (perhaps those are not expressed in the current time zone?)

Answer (score -1):

Do you think like this?
Its not exactly you want but can help you. This method makes UTC time at same value as is local time

```
+(NSDate *) dateAsCurrentTime
{
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    NSCalendar *calNew = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    calNew.timeZone=[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
    NSDate *utcDate = [calNew dateFromComponents:components];

    return utcDate;
}
```

Comment: But I am working off an array of existing dates, not trying to get the current date's hour.

Comment: I dont understand your question there, it should be checking in your current calendar settings? Or do you know time zone of other dates you check to?